# Expression choice between 'an English teacher in China' and ' a Chinese English teacher'

Tags: expressions

I am writing my essay for graduate application. This is the question that puzzles me.
Which one is better, 'as **an English teacher in China**'  or 'as **a Chinese English teacher**' or 'as **a bilingual teacher**'?

What I want to express here is I am an English teacher in China (I am Chinese).  BTW, I am a senior college student.

Comment: Good question! "As a teacher of English in China" might be less ambiguous. Another option.. hm... "as a Chinese native teacher of English in China"? I'm not sure.

Comment: **native Chinese teacher of English** might sound better. **In China** may not be necessary since her fluency is great enough to teach English (implied anywhere), **in China** may help but probably won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

> English teacher in China.

This can mean that the teacher is from England or it can mean that the teacher teaches English, as a language. Considering the latter, the ethnicity of the teacher remains unspecified.

> Chinese English teacher.

This could mean that the teacher is a Chinese nationality or a Chinese origin, who teaches English. This seems apt. Or you could rephrase :

> **I am a teacher from China who teaches English.**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Varun, I think I'll go with ' Chinese English teacher' XD

Answer (score 0):

You are both, an **English teacher** in China, and a **Chinese English teacher**.

I would say depends where and for what you are applying. If it is obvious from you application that you are a Chinese national, then **English teacher** or that you **teach English** is good. If it is obvious you are ethnic Chinese but from an English speaking country, then emphasis **in China**. You're not technically a **bilingual teacher** since you are only teaching one language, but you might want to stress that you are **bilingual**.  In other words, stress the **contrast**.